# How to change font size in TextBlock, when the text is in the second line

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm looking for method to change font size in TextBlock if text goes to second line. 
How can I know, when the text proceed to the second line? 
Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you trying to keep it from wrapping?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to have horizontal scroll... I'd like to decrease the text

Comment: What will happen when the text is extremely long?

Comment: @Jonesy: very good point. Further, @SlaviS, you'll probably need to consume the [`SizeChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event and then change the `FontSize` appropriately to get it to size back to its original size.

Comment: @Jones Nothing, I trying to make a calculator. So, my text will have max 20 character, but for start the font size is really big, and I'd like to decrease it when the text won't to fit in the TextBlock.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is handle the `TextChanged` event and in the handler check the length of the text.

If the text is `<= 20` you keep the original size. If it's `> 20` but `<= 25` you decrease the font size by say 3 points. An so on until you reach a limit of characters you want to support, say 50 or something.

You will probably need to disable `Textbox` text wrapping so that you only have a single line of text.

Comment: :) Well you are changing text from somewhere right? Just do this there then.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping with a Viewbox may give you the functionality you're after:

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Width="50" Height="50">
    <TextBlock Text="Test" />
</Viewbox>
```

source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13268895/1202600

Comment: You'll need to set the Width and Height of the Viewbox to be the size of you want for your calculator display rather than the height and width of the TextBlock. I tested the above in kaxaml and it worked okay. Can you provide an example of your non-working code?

Comment: So, for example. I've TextBlock 200x400 and I'd like to display text in field 200x300. I have to add Viewbox with this width and height?

Comment: If you have a 200x400 TextBlock and you want to display text in a field that is 200x300 within that and (according to your original question) want the text to autosize then yes. You will need a TextBlock of 200x400 containing a ViewBox of 200x300 which contains a text block with your text. Basically a 200x400 TextBlock containing the above answer but with and height set to 200 and 300 respectively.